# Plotting scalar field

Tags: r

I was searching for a way to plot this function as a scalar field, in particular as continuous scalar field:

```
library(rgl)

points = seq(-2, 0, length=20)

XY = expand.grid(X=points,Y=-points)
Zf <- function(X,Y){
     X^2-Y^2;
     }
Z <- Zf(XY$X, XY$Y)

open3d()
rgl.surface(x=points, y=matrix(Z,20), coords=c(1,3,2),z=-points)
axes3d()
```

A scalar field is usually plotted with two axis X and Y, where Z is represent by a colour( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field)

With ggplot() I can do this:

```
daf=data.frame(XY$X,XY$Y,Z)

ggplot(daf)+geom_point(aes(XY.X,XY.Y,color=Z))
```

[image]

But still not a continuous field.

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific/explicit about what you want that your code is not doing?

Comment: Do you just want `geom_tile` instead? `ggplot(daf)+geom_tile(aes(XY.X,XY.Y,fill=Z))`

Comment: not quite geom_tile just uses rectangles instead of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by the 'image' function:

```
Z <- outer(points, points, Zf)
image(points, points, Z)
```

[image: scalar field]

This method just uses nearest neighbor interpolation, but if you want a smoother representation, you can use other types of interpolation:

```
library(fields)

# Bilinear interpolation
interp_points = seq(-2, 0, length = 200)
interp_bilinear <- interp.surface(list(x = X, y = Y, z = Z), 
                                  loc = expand.grid(interp_points, interp_points))

image(interp_points, interp_points, matrix(interp_bilinear, 200, 200))
```

[image: Linear interpolation]

```
# Bicubic interpolation
library(akima)
interp_bicubic <- bicubic.grid(X, Y, Z, xlim = c(-2, 0), ylim = c(-2, 0), 
                               dx = 2 / (200 - 1), dy = 2 / (200 - 1))
image(interp_bicubic)
```

[image: Bicubic interpolation]

The difference between different interpolation schemes becomes clearer when you have fewer observations or more wildly behaving functions:

[image: comparison]